# Problem- can't get the accurate coordinates of mouse on page resize, when using html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanted to create this **Pixel Effect** from [Frontend Expert](https://www.frontendexpert.io/).

Although I was able to implement the entire pixel effect on a full screen canvas:

```
const canvas = getElementById('canvas');

canvas.height = window.innerHeight; // Gives the canvas height of fullscreen
canvas.width= window.innerWidth; // Gives the canvas width of fullscreen
```

and got the coordinates of the mouse pretty easily

```
const mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined
}
canvas.addEventListner('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.x;
  mouse.y = e.y;
}
```

About now the canvas width and height was equal to that of the document, therefore, it was pretty easy to get the exact coordinates of the mouse.
But when I tried to implement it with **800px X 400px** dimensions and used a flexbox with it (like shown in the website) my mouse coordinates got completely messed up and I spent hours in fixing but wasn't able to get the accuracy as shown in the above website. Also there were some issues related to resize.

I would like to know how can I preserve the mouse accuracy.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use e.x and e.y, even though used in an event listener for tha canvas, they return the mouse coordinate relative to the top-left pixel of the entire page, not just the canvas. If by messed up, you mean that anywhere you click, the pixel effect is offset in some constant direction, this may be your issue and you should replace e.x and e.y with e.clientX and e.clientY. The ‘client’ in e.clientX refers to which element the listener is for and specifies to give event coordinates relative to that element instead of the page. If it is messed up in some other way, then I don’t think I have an answer for that.